# How can one show that $ f(0)\ln(\frac{b}{a})=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int_{\epsilon a}^{\epsilon b} \frac{f(x)}{x}dx$?

Tags: integration, limits, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:[0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function. If $a>0$, show that:

$$ f(0)\ln(\frac{b}{a})=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int_{\epsilon a}^{\epsilon b} \frac{f(x)}{x}dx$$

Tried using Riemann sum, but did not succeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int_{\epsilon a}^{ \epsilon b} \frac {f(x)}{x} dx = \int_{\epsilon a}^ {\epsilon b}\left[\frac {f(0)}{x} +\frac {f(x) - f(0)}{x}\right] dx = f(0)[\ln (\epsilon b) - \ln (\epsilon a)] + \int_{\epsilon a}^ {\epsilon b} \frac {f(x) - f(0)}{x}dx$$

The last integral goes to 0 as $\epsilon \to 0$ because $a > 0$ (and I am also assuming $b > 0$), so $x$ is not near $0$.

So the final answer is $f(0)[\ln (\epsilon) +\ln (b) -(\ln (\epsilon) + \ln(a))]$

and this goes to $f(0)\ln \dfrac{b}{a}$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: Um $x$ will be near $0$.

Comment: TO JLA: Just to add to the answer already given, the second integral is bounded by $\epsilon(b - a)M$ where $M$ is bound for $|f(x) - f(0)|/x$. Clearly to get the highest estimate of $M$ we need to replace in $x$ in denom by $a\epsilon$ so that the integral is not greater than $((b - a)/a)|f(x) - f(0)|$ and this tends to zero as $\epsilon \to 0$ because of continuity of $f$ at $x = 0$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh looked at your edit and couldn't tell what you did.  Did I mistype something?  I appreciate your addendum re limiting the f(x)-f(0) integral.

Comment: I do not quite understand why the second integral goes to zero

Comment: To Betty: I just made equations look better, no change in mathematical content. Just a bit of beautification by using appropriate latex commands.

Comment: To Henfe: See my previous comment where I explain why the second integral goes to zero.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh  I see you made the fractions bigger -- how does one do that?

Comment: Learning LaTeX is bit out of context here, but its a small trick so here it goes. One mechanism is to use \dfrac instead of \frac command. Another mechanism is to use $\$$\displaystyle <math content> $\$$ instead of just $\$$ <math content>$\$$. A third approach is also possible: put your content between $\$\$$ and $\$\$$ instead of $\$$ and $\$$. Following this last approach (as I have done here) will also put your equation in center alignment.

Comment: Thanks for the hints.  I think we'll survive the context.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes that's true, but so? The poster claimed that as $\epsilon\to 0$ $x$ will not be near $0$, which isn't true. This needs to be fixed.

Comment: To JLA: Please consider my comment (where I have given justification for second integral) and the answer by Betty together. If you prefer to remove the phrase "x will not be near 0" from Betty's answer then drop a comment to Betty suggesting this. I am sure Betty will fix this minor glitch. Or you may edit this answer of Betty and someone will approve your edit.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Consider first the case where $f(0)=0$. Prove that the integral in question is zero. Then apply this result to $f(x)-f(0)$.

Answer (score 2):

One way to look at this is with the [mean value theorem for integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_mean_value_theorem_for_integration)

since $a$ is positive, and I assume $b$ is too, then $\frac 1 x$ is positive in the interval    $(\epsilon a, \ \epsilon b )$ ( or negative if $\epsilon $ aproches $0$ from the left), and it doesn't change sign, thus:
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int_{\epsilon a}^{\epsilon b} \frac{f(x)}{x}dx = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} f(c)\int_{\epsilon a}^{\epsilon b} \frac{1}{x}dx
$$

for some $ c \in (\epsilon a, \ \epsilon b ) $, therfore
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int_{\epsilon a}^{\epsilon b} \frac{f(x)}{x}dx = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} f(c) \Big [\ln(\epsilon b)-\ln(\epsilon a) \Big ]\\=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} f(c)  \ln(\frac b a)
$$
and because $\epsilon a<c<\epsilon b$ and both $\epsilon a $ and $\epsilon b$ aprach $0$ as $\epsilon $ aproches $0$, then, by the squeeze theorem, $c$ aproaches $0$, and because $f$ is continous, it doesn't matter how $c$ aproches $0$, thus:

$$
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int_{\epsilon a}^{\epsilon b} \frac{f(x)}{x}dx = f(0)  \ln(\frac b a)
$$