# Let $f:[0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function. If $a>0$, show that:

Tags: real-analysis

Let  $f:[0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function. If $a>0$, show that:

$$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int_{\epsilon a}^{\epsilon b} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}dx=0$$

This question came from:[How can one show that $ f(0)\ln(\frac{b}{a})=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int_{\epsilon a}^{\epsilon b} \frac{f(x)}{x}dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532785/how-can-one-show-that-f0-ln-fracba-lim-epsilon-rightarrow-0-int)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing that $b > a$ - otherwise interchange the roles - you have

$$\begin{align}
\left\lvert \int_{\epsilon a}^{\epsilon b}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}\,dx\right\rvert
&\leqslant \int_{\epsilon a}^{\epsilon b} \frac{\lvert f(x) - f(0)\rvert}{x}\,dx\\
&\leqslant \sup_{0 \leqslant \xi \leqslant \epsilon b} \lvert f(\xi) - f(0)\rvert \cdot\int_{\epsilon a}^{\epsilon b} \frac{dx}{x}\\
&= \log \frac{b}{a}\cdot \sup_{0 \leqslant \xi \leqslant \epsilon b} \lvert f(\xi) - f(0)\rvert.
\end{align}$$

Since $f$ is assumed continuous in $0$, the supremum tends to $0$ for $\epsilon\to 0$.